# Как с помощью скрипта заменить запятую на точку при вводе цены в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

как скриптом автоматически поменять введенную запятую на точку непосредственно при вводе запятой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('input#hax').on('input', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\,/g, '.'));
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(
    /(?=(\d+\.\d{2})).+|(\.(?=\.))|([^\.\d])|(^\D)/gi, '$1'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='hax' />
```

Comment: SLy_huh спасибо! А можете сюда добавить условие, что после точки нельзя больше вводить точку и можно ввести максимум две цифры?

Comment: в случае проверки по нажатию клавиши выходит не универсально. например, не сработает при добавлении значения через ctrl+V или правую кнопку мыши

Comment: lexxl, как тогда быть? .on("input" тоже не помог для ctrl+V, вставка мышкой отключена, поэтому не столь важно.

Comment: @Евгений изменил код, теперь работает и на вставку

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @Евгений добавил выполнение первого условия, теперь шаблон - любое кол-во цифр до `.` и 2 после